# NotAMockException when trying to use verify method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

My first steps with unit tests and Mockito. I would like to use verify() method to check if it was called once.

```
public class CarService {

    private final VinService vinService;

    public void checkCar(String VIN) {
        (here there is some business logic like:create list, pass the VIN, and add Consumer)

        vinService.checkVin(list, VIN, consumer); //checkVin inside VinService.class is also void
    }
}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CarServiceTest {

    private static final String VIN = "1G100000000000000"

    @Mock
    private CarService carService;

    @Mock
    private VinService vinService;

    @Test
    void vinShouldBeCheckedSuccessfully() {

        //when
        carService.checkCar(VIN);

        //then
        Mockito.verify(vinService, Mockito.times(1)).checkVIN(
                Mockito.anyList(),
                Mockito.anyString(),
                Mockito.any()); // Consumer parameter
    }
}
```

However I am getting the error:

```
 org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
    Argument passed to verify() is of type VinService and is not a mock!
    Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!
    See the examples of correct verifications:
        verify(mock).someMethod();
        verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
        verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();
```

Could you help me to understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it`s very simple. You just need to use **@InjectMocks** instead **@Mock** for the service that you are testing:

```
@InjectMocks
private CarService carService;
```

This annotation says that Mockito will properly inject all mocks into your service(VinService into CarService).

**Updated for comment**
if you have somewhere initializing your service then you can easily add your mock inside test.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    public class CarServiceTest {

        private static final String VIN = "1G100000000000000"

        @InjectMocks
        private CarService carService;

        @Test
        void vinShouldBeCheckedSuccessfully() {
            VinService vinService = Mockito.mock(VinService.class);

            //when
            carService.checkCar(VIN);

            //then
            Mockito.verify(vinService, Mockito.times(1)).checkVIN(
                Mockito.anyList(),
                Mockito.anyString(),
                Mockito.any()); // Consumer parameter
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have still the same error

Comment: Verify that the vinService dependency is used within the CarService class, check your dependencies in gradle/maven too.

Comment: I found possible reason. Inside test class I am initializing CarService in additional method: carService = new CarService(vinService) and vinService = new VinService(anotherService). So I have real object and @Mock. I suppose in this case it is not possible to use verify method because it can be probably used only on Mock.

Comment: Updated my comment. Just mock Class inside the test. and your test will use this mock.